# Ruby on rails 5.2 - background image with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, background

I upgraded my app to rails 5.2 and I am using the active storage of rails.

In case I want to use the picture I uploaded as a  background, which method is the best? I would like to use a resized picture 300x300 for the background.

```
<div style="background: ... ">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="index-img">
    <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url(<%= rails_blob_url(@user.avatar) %>)"></div>
</div>
```

then can style it in css like

```
.index-img{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: $grey;
}
.bg-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include background-image();
}
```

Comment: Be aware that you should use double quotes around the path, to prevent any file names with single quotes `'` from breaking the CSS. E.g. `background-image: url("<%= rails_blob_url(...) %>")`

Answer (score -1):

You can write css on page itself like below. Then use in div.

```
<style media="screen">
  #div_id { background-image: url(<%= image_path @user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 300]) %>) !important;
  ......
  }
</style>

<div id="div_id">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am now getting the following error message: The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: Your image path return blank string. Try pass right object and it will work.

Comment: Hello, actually no it didn't work. I found then rails_blob_url which worked.