# Rails Active Storage - Background Image invalid property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So in my app i have a card where i want to dynamically set the background image via ActiveStorage like so:

```
  <div class="card" style="background-image: url(<%= rails_blob_path(post.images.first) %>)">

 </div>
```

however, the image is not visible. Inside chrome i also get in the element.style property `"invalid type property"` as an error.

If i inspect the card element, the url is loaded like so:

```
`background-image: url(/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9be6ec89650623cc4a22214c34635f2924f8feea/Frame%20(1).png)`
```

Taking the url and adding localhost:3000 to it loads the image:

```
localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9be6ec89650623cc4a22214c34635f2924f8feea/Frame%20(1).png
```

Rendering the image normally inside an img tag works fine:

```
<%= image_tag(post.images.first) %>
```

Also, changing`rails_blob_path` to `rails_blob_url` makes no difference at all. The only change is that there is a localhost:3000 added to the url in rails_blob_url:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9be6ec89650623cc4a22214c34635f2924f8feea/Frame%20(1).png
```

Adding a height/width to the card class results also in no difference.

Here is a reference i've found, seems like they are using the same approach as i do: [Ruby on rails 5.2 - background image with active storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381990/ruby-on-rails-5-2-background-image-with-active-storage)

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Greetings!

Comment: Try removing forward slash, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075730/css-background-image-url-path

Comment: Are you trying to make the image downloadable or just show it?

Comment: No download required. The image needs to be set as an div background, like shown above. Rendering the image via image_tag works and getting the download url works also. This has something with CSS to do i guess and the way i inject the background-image url.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all of your input!

I was able to fix it. Just in case someone runs into the same issue:

Add single quotes to your path:

Solution:

```
 <div class="card" style="background-image: url('<%= rails_blob_url(post.images.first) %>'); height: 100px; background-position: center;">
```

For comparison (before):

```
 <div class="card" style="background-image: url(<%= rails_blob_path(post.images.first) %>)">
```

Double quotes don't work in this example.

This would be probably not even an issue if i just would have used the scss file instead of adding it directly to the div.

Cheers!