# Active Storage: filenames with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

In my application, users can change the background image of a banner. They upload the file using Simple Form and Active Storage. It's working correctly but we had a user trying to upload a file name `banner-website.png (2).png`. The file is uploaded and saved but doesn't appear as a background image. I guess this happens because of special characters in the filename.

What is recommended to avoid such situations? Do we need to sanitize file names?

Comment: What code are you using to put the image in the background?  What does the resulting HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: The code I'm using to show the image is `style="background-image: url(<%= rails_blob_url(@theme.background_image);" %>)`.<br /> In the HTML, it appears like this: `<div class="card border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0 border-bottom rounded-0 mb-2" style="background-image: url(http-marble2-lvh-me-3000-rails-active_storage-blobs-redirect-eyjfcmfpbhmionsibwvzc2fnzsi6ikjbahbidz09iiwizxhwijpudwxslcjwdxiioijibg9ix2lkin19-56310f5c9cba27c1d79e1cfa079c6c669baca78b-banner-website-png-20-2-png);`. In the CSS it appears the same URL as the background-image.

Comment: It looks like it is sanitizing or parameterizing all the URL, right? (http-marble2-...) But I didn't add any method to do it... I saw that in my Gemfile.lock I have ` rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)`. I don't know if it changes something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution here: [Rails Active Storage - Background Image invalid property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769336/rails-active-storage-background-image-invalid-property)

Adding a single quote around the URL solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

1. Check the console and tried to view the CSS and see if the full link
   is being populated? Try checking the CSS code and copy the link to
   an address bar to see if the image loads from that direction.
2. Check the users png file to make sure its not corrupt. PNG headers that are corrupt can cause issues displaying in a website.
3. Check to see if your sanitizing plugin is causing an issue with that file. I have never used that one so regarding that I cannot say.

I tried uploading a file with a same name into my Rails 6 testbench (vanilla with active storage and stimulus js) and it works fine. It could be a conflicting CSS code too.

Just my 2 cents.